# Is equivalent destruction undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, json, c++20

Will running a 'equivalent' procedure to an objects destructor result in undefined behavior under the standard?

Example:

Assume we wish to represent a directed acyclic tree, with homogeneous nodes, with root ownership. A problem with deep-structures is recursive operations. Almost all operations can be implemented, of course, with an allocated stack. However, can the nodes remain homogeneous, and automatically destroyed, without undefined behavior?

Namely by bypassing recursive destruction by doing a logically equivalent stack based destruction operation from the root node. (Ignoring possible exceptions from allocation)

```cpp
class Node {
    // ...

    // Assuming unique ownership
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    ~Node() { destroy_deep(); }

    void destroy()
    {
        // Assert: left == nullptr && right == nullptr
        // ...
    }

    void destroy_deep()
    {
        std::vector<Node *> nodes{ this };



        while (nodes.size()) {
            Node &next = *nodes.back();

            if (!next.left && !next.right) {
                next.destroy();
                
                if (next != this) {
                    // Assume such a deallocate function
                    deallocate(next);
                }
                 
                nodes.pop_back();
            } else {
                if (next.left) {
                    nodes.push_back(next.right);
                }

                if (next.right) {
                    nodes.push_back(next.left);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Or you could create an actual tree class, whose destructor cleans up the nodes in a non-recursive manner. Exposing the nodes and having outside code maintain a root and other invariants seems ill-advised for other reasons too.

Comment: As long as every object is destructed exactly once  (which includes, if the object is created with a `new` expression, correctly releasing it with a single corresponding `delete` expression) behaviour will be well-defined regardless of the order in which objects are destroyed.    Destroy any object more than once, or destroy it in a way inconsistent with how it was created then behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Given it is a DAG, simply changing your `Node*` to `shared_ptr<Node>` should solve your problem (of course some other codes need to be changed accordingly) .  You don't need to write any code to do the destruction.  With Rule-of-Zero in mind, in most scenario we don't need to write any dtor/copy-ctor/move-ctor/assignment/move-operator by proper use of `unique_ptr` / `shared_ptr` etc

Comment: @AdrianShum That will cause stack overflow through destructor chain if you delete a root of very deep tree, won't it?

Comment: "Assuming unique ownership" then use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @Quimby - As long as the "destructor chain" is finite (e.g. no infinite recursion, for example due to objects mutually referencing each other) there should not be any stack overflow.  Modern optimising compilers tend to do a better job of optimising code (e.g. translating recursive code into an iterative equivalent or managing low-level resource usage) than programmers do.

Comment: @Peter I somehow doubt a `Node` with member `std::shared_ptr<Node> child` can get any sort of tail-call optimization in `~Node` for releasing the block if `child`. IMHO it will lead to ordinary call of child's destructor `~Node`. For long paths, this recursion could stack overflow easily.

Comment: *"`// Assume such a deallocate function`"* -- the details of this function combined with details of how nodes are allocated are rather central to whether or not the behavior is defined. And you probably don't have to be so mysterious -- change your pointer type from `Node *` to `std::unique_ptr<Node>` and change `deallocate(next);` to `next.reset();`. That would be enough for us to assume the deallocation matches the allocation. Unfortunately, it might also make your question moot, as it might solve the remaining issues in your code (infinite loop and multiple de-allocation) as a side-effect.

Comment: @Slava good catch. I have only paid attention to DAG but missed that "unique ownership" comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, can the nodes remain homogeneous, and automatically destroyed, without undefined behavior?

Sure. First of all let's use proper data type for pointers, as you assume unique ownership we should use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class Node {
    using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node>;
// ...

// Assuming unique ownership
   NodePtr left;
   NodePtr right;
};
```

Ok now this class will properly manage it's data, but it will destroy the tree recursively. Now to avoid recursion we just create our own custom destructor:

```
Node::~Node()
{
     if( ! (left || right) ) // optimization
         return;
     std::vector<NodePtr> nodes;
     auto populate = [&nodes] ( Node *n ) {
         if( n->left ) nodes.push_back( std::move( n->left ) );
         if( n->right ) nodes.push_back( std::move( n->right ) );
     };
     populate( this );
     while( !nodes.empty() ) {
         auto n = std::move( nodes.back() );
         nodes.pop_back();
         populate( n.get() );
     }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/y2Ele4)

That's it, it will destroy children using `std::vector` as stack.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is sound, but your implementation does indeed have undefined behavior. (I hope you did not assume the approach is flawed simply because your implementation crashed.) Take this as a lesson in utilizing the standard library to avoid bugs, as the biggest flaw would have been avoided if you had used `std::unique_ptr` to model unique ownership instead of relying on a comment.

## The problems (undefined behavior)

1. **Infinite loop:** Assume the root has children. You start the process by adding the root to the `nodes` vector. Then you enter the loop and process the root. The root has children, so you push the children onto `nodes` and go to the next iteration. Suppose we eventually get back to the case where `nodes.size()` is `1` (otherwise, we already know the loop is infinite). Then the loop will again process the root. The root has children, so you push the children onto `nodes` and go to the next iteration.
   You can never empty the vector because you never set the child pointers to null (which would have been automatic with `unique_ptr`). While an infinite loop is bad by itself, in this case it leads to another problem as a side-effect (see the next point).
2. **Multiple de-allocations:** Does your assumed `deallocate` function allow de-allocating the same object multiple times? Probably not. If it mimics the behavior of `delete`, then it does not. Thanks the the infinite loop, your code would attempt to de-allocate at least one of the leaves an infinite number of times. "Would" except it might crash the second time.
   Note that a similar problem might arise with calling `destroy()` multiple times. However, a re-entrant `destroy` is more likely than a re-entrant `deallocate`.
3. **Null de-reference:** When calling `back()`, the retrieved pointer is immediately de-referenced. This assumes that null pointers are never stored in the vector. However – perhaps this is a typo, but it has a major consequence – null pointers are stored in the vector whenever a node has exactly one child. If a node has a left child (so `next.left` evaluates to truth), then the **right** child is pushed on the vector, and vice-versa.

## A solution

While the better solution is to use `unique_ptr` (as in the other answer), your approach is salvageable. After addressing the above problems plus the syntax error present in `next != this`, your code works. In fact, you don't even need to "Assume such a deallocate function", as `delete` will work just as well. While `delete` will call the destructor in addition to de-allocating memory, the destructor is not recursive for leaf nodes. And de-allocation is invoked only for leaf nodes.

If you must use a custom de-allocation function, then just make sure the nodes were created using the corresponding allocation function. Note that using a custom de-allocation function is compatible with using `unique_ptr`, and in fact using `unique_ptr` might be a way to ensure that the allocation and de-allocation functions match.

I am assuming that `destroy()` is re-entrant. If this is not the case, then more adjustments will be needed. Perhaps move the call to `destroy()` to the destructor (after calling `destroy_deep`), since there is no longer an issue with too-deep recursion.

Here is your `destroy_deep()` with the fixes and the assumption that the "deallocate function" is actually `delete`. Some cleanup could/should still be done; this is supposed to highlight the changes (marked with `///`-style comments).

```cpp
void destroy_deep()
{
    std::vector<Node *> nodes{ this };

    /// STYLE: Using `!empty()`  is clearer than implicitly
    ///        converting `size()` to a boolean.
    while (!nodes.empty()) {
        Node &next = *nodes.back();

        if (!next.left && !next.right) {
            next.destroy();
                
            /// ERROR: Could not compare `Node` to `Node*`.
            ///        So I changed `next` to `&next`.
            if (&next != this) {
                // Assume such a deallocate function
                /// Rather than assume, I'll just delete.
                delete &next;
            }
            nodes.pop_back();
        } else {
            if (next.left) {
                /// ERROR: Original code pushed the *right* child because
                ///        the *left* child is not null???
                nodes.push_back(next.left);
                /// ERROR: Infinite loop without the following:
                next.left = nullptr;
            }

            if (next.right) {
                /// ERROR: Original code pushed the *left* child because
                ///        the *right* child is not null???
                nodes.push_back(next.right);
                /// ERROR: Infinite loop without the following:
                next.right = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The major fix is setting `left` and `right` to null after pushing them onto the vector. You would not have been able to forget this if using `unique_ptr` since a `unique_ptr` would have to be moved, not copied, to the vector, and since this move would cause the original pointer to become null.